# How does ὁ ἐρχόμενος relate to the Father? How is the father "coming"? (Ἀποκάλυψις [Revelation] 1,4)

Tags: greek, revelation

> Ἀποκάλυψις 1,4α Ἰωάννης ταῖς ἑπτὰ ἐκκλησίαις ταῖς ἐν τῇ Ἀσίᾳ · χάρις ὑμῖν καὶ εἰρήνη ἀπὸ ὁ ὢν καὶ ὁ ἦν καὶ ὁ ἐρχόμενος ...

From context, this is a reference to the Father (1,4β refers to the Holy Spirit and 1,5 to Jesus). I understand how God the Father "is being" and "was being", but how is he "coming"?

Comment: I found an interesting note on this topic in Thayer: See the end of definition 1b (http://biblehub.com/greek/2064.htm) "in the periphrasis of the name of Jehovah, ὁ ὤν καί ὁ ἦν καί ὁ ἐρχόμενος, it is equivalent to ἐσόμενος, Revelation 1:4; Revelation 4:8"

Answer (score 1):

Buttman states,<sup>1</sup>

> Present [tense] frequently stands where things still future are spoken of-consequently that the Present comprises within itself the Future force of the verb...

Furthermore, in categorizing these kinds of present tense verbs, he describes one such category wherein

> The idea of the verb is such a nature that of itself it includes the force of the Future. This holds...pre-eminently of two verbal ideas: that of *coming*, ἔρχεσθαι, together with its synonymes ὑπάγειν, πορεύσθαι, etc., and that of *becoming*, γίνεσθαι. As in ἥκω (see No. 9) there inheres a Perfect force (I *have come, am present*), so in ἔρχομαι a Future (I *come, shall appear*)... **That the Present ἔρχομαι in all the Moods takes the place of εἶμι** (which by the Attics was commonly employed in a Future sense, but in the N.T. as a simple verb is not used) has already been mentioned (p. [50](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1gSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q&f=true)) and is plain from innumerable examples; as, [John iv. 23](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/4/23/t_concf_1001023) ἔρχεται ὥρα καὶ νῦν ἐστιν, [xiv. 3](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/14/3/t_concf_1011003) ἐὰν ἑτοιμάσω τόπον ὑμῖν, πάλιν ἔρχομαι καὶ παραλήψομαι ὑμᾶς, [i. 30](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/1/30/t_concf_998030) ὀπίσω μου ἔρχεται ἀνὴρ etc., especially in the Part. ὁ ἐρχόμενος of the Messiah [Matt. iii. 11](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mat/3/11/t_concf_932011) etc., the formula in the [**Apocalypse**](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/rev/1/1/t_concf_1168008) ὁ ὢν καὶ ὁ ἦν καὶ ὁ ἐρχόμενος of God, τὰ ἐρχόμενα ([John xvi. 13](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/16/13/t_concf_1013013)), ὁ αἰὼν ὁ ἐρχόμενος ([Mark x. 30](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mar/10/30/t_concf_967030), etc.) of the future.

In other words, ὁ ἐρχόμενος is simply equivalent to ὁ ἔσται (and yes, that's a solecism, just like ὁ ἦν), although the author could have wrote ὁ ἐσόμενος instead. In summary, in this context, ὁ ἐρχόμενος does not describe the Father as “He who comes,” but rather, “He who shall be.”

---

### References

Buttman, Alexander. [*A Grammar of the New Testament Greek.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1gSAAAAIAAJ) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Andover: Draper, 1873.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> p. [203-204](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1gSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q&f=true)

Answer (score 0):

ὁ ἐρχόμενος could merely be saying that God will continue to be in the future but if taken as "will be coming in the future" then we see that graphically described in chapter 21.

The traditional hope of the Christian is to "go to heaven" but the scriptural hope has always been to live with God in the promised land:

> Rev 21:2  And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down
>   from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. 
>   Rev 21:3  And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the
>   tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them, and they
>   shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be their
>   God.

Hence the prayer "Thy kingdom come". And:

> Heb 11:8  By faith Abraham, when he was called to go out into a place
>   which he should after receive for an inheritance, obeyed; and he went
>   out, not knowing whither he went.  Heb 11:9  By faith he sojourned in
>   the land of promise, as in a strange country, dwelling in tabernacles
>   with Isaac and Jacob, the heirs with him of the same promise:  Heb
>   11:10  For he looked for a city which hath foundations, whose builder
>   and maker is God.

So the description of God's dwelling place descending shows that God is going lives in a mobile home which he will relocate to his sacred property in the middle east. This is him "coming".

> Mic_4:7  And I will make her that halted a remnant, and her that was
>   cast far off a strong nation: and the LORD shall reign over them in
>   mount Zion from henceforth, even for ever.
>
> Isa 24:23  Then the moon shall be confounded, and the sun ashamed,
>   when the LORD of hosts shall reign in mount Zion, and in Jerusalem,
>   and before his ancients gloriously.

The synopsis/Cliff Notes version of the Revelation is this:

- divine terrorism poured out from the sky will demoralize the nations
- Jesus will gather the saints to the middle east and reign for a thousand years
- Jesus will step down and become just another Joe and God himself will descend from the sky and rule alone forever

In this way God is the one who is coming.

For an even shorter synopsis of the Revelation:

> 1Co 15:24  Then cometh the end, when he shall have delivered up the
>   kingdom to God, even the Father; when he shall have put down all rule
>   and all authority and power.